# doorkeeper integration with Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

Following the instructions (I thought) in the doorkeeper github readme, I got as far the `before_action`.

```
class ReadingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize! # Require access token for all actions
...
end
```

RubyMine complains that `:doorkeeper_authorize!` is not defined in scope. 
If I run it anyhow, I get:

```
Processing by ReadingsController#index as HTML
Filter chain halted as :doorkeeper_authorize! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

on the console, and a completely blank result. It looks like the regular result page when I look at view source.

Well, is this failure, or is this actually telling me I'm unauthorized? And if it is, why do I do to wire up a redirect to allow someone to actually, well authenticate?

Comment: Doorkeeper provides a way for **other** websites to authenticate using an existing account in app powered by Doorkeeper. Doorkeeper does not provide authentication by itself. I may have misunderstood the question, please clarify it if that's the case. It's unclear to me how you're trying to test desired behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see. An oauth2 PROVIDER. I'm looking for an oauth2 _consumer_. Whoops.

Comment: Yep, that's right! I've had a job interview recently where I was asked to implement [a pass-through OAuth2 provider](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server) and [a test client](https://github.com/D-side/auth-client) for it. You may want to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [a working example I've built a while before](https://github.com/D-side/auth-server/blob/master/config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb#L6), your code is failing in a completely unexpected place: in Doorkeeper's initializer in a block like this:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  current_user || begin
    session[:guest_return_url] = request.fullpath
    redirect_to(user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook))
  end
end
```

I do not know what do **you** have in that block, but in general it should return an object that should be treated as a **resource owner**. Doorkeeper failed because that block failed to do so. To implement this block in my example, I'm using Devise's `current_user` helper and a fallback `redirect_to` for when a user is not authenticated (this is executed in a `before_action` after all).

So for Doorkeeper to "let you in" you need to tell it "how to recognize the owner". That is **authentication** that Doorkeeper doesn't handle.